# black edge lines not showing in Freestyle

Tags: freestyle

No doubt I'm missing something obvious, but I can't get the black line edges in Freestyle to show, either in the viewport or in the render. Any ideas why? I'm in Eevee.

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to render - freestyle is a post-process effect and doesn't display in the viewport. You may want to consider [Line Art](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modifiers/generate/line_art.html) in order to see the effect in the viewport.

Comment: It's not showing up in the render either

Comment: @PowersVideo Try severly decreasing the amount of geometry - for example to 6 cubes. I suspect it does work, but you don't have the patience for Freestyle to finish work - which with too many objects could as well never finish due to running out of resources.

Answer (score 0):

You have "As Render Pass" selected in your freestyle settings, which won't show up in a render unless you've composited the pass in using the compositor. Unchecking "As Render Pass" will cause it to show up in the combined render pass automatically.

[image: As Render Pass]

Examples of compositor setups and the Freestyle As Render Pass option:

[image: As Render Pass unchecked with default compositor nodes]
[image: As Render Pass checked with default compositor nodes]
[image: As Render Pass checked and pass composited using the Alpha Over node]